# imu_link does not rotate?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i am using mpu9250 by using  this package   [jeskesen /i2c_imu](https://github.com/jeskesen/i2c_imu) and run  `rosrun rviz rviz` .

But `imu_link` doesn't rotate by rotating the real imu, the `imu_link`  is fixed with `base_link`.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/359813/imu_link-does-not-rotate?/) by [Ahmed_Desoky](https://answers.ros.org/users/49283/ahmed_desoky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2020-08-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2020-08-20**:
What are you using for frame in RVIZ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

add

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="dyn_controller" xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">
  <joint name="imu_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link" />
    <child link="imu_link" />
  </joint>
</robot>
```

---

Originally posted by [Ahmed_Desoky](https://answers.ros.org/users/49283/ahmed_desoky/) with karma: 23 on 2020-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0